# Looking for the name of a book about a robot that gains sentience

Tags: story-identification, robots

I read a book when I was much younger which follows the life of a robot which was built during world war 2.

He gets covered in blood and somehow this grants his sentience.

The rest of the novel follows his centuries long life.

I remember he was a racing driver at one point.

He strives to become more human and has fake skin/hair added as well as some kind of artificial penis.

I have no idea how to track it down... any help??

Comment: It might be helpful to know about **when** you read the book. "When you were much younger" does not really tell us much.

Comment: I vaguely recall a novel like this, but it starts with the robot walking away from two old people. It turns out the two people had made the robot and given their own life force to the robot to grant it consciousness - that's why they looked old. The underlying theme is the robot's search for what constitutes consciousness. At one point the robot has a penis made and there is an (unnecessarily :-) lengthy chapter on what he gets up to with it. Could this be the book? If so I don't recall any mention of WW2.

Comment: @JohnRennie, that sounds like a "Roderik" story buy John Sladek. As for the original question, the only robot's life story that it fits would be the many stories about Adam Link written in the 1930s by Eando Binder.

Comment: @Covertwalrus: I have the complete Roderick, and it is not the book I'm thinking of.

Comment: John Rennie. The book you were trying to remember is called "The soul of the Robot" by Barrington J Bailey. However, from what I recall of it, that book doesn't match the OP search